# spring-cloud-starter-eureka is not resolving when i use Finchley.M5

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud

Trying to create my own api gateway using spring cloud gateway

Below is my build.gradle file,

```
buildscript {
  ext {
    springBootVersion = "1.5.9.RELEASE"
  }


apply plugin: "io.spring.dependency-management"
apply plugin: "org.springframework.boot"


dependencies {
  compile(
      'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web',
      'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat',
      'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator',
      'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-webflux',
      'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-gateway',
      'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-eureka'
  )

  testCompile(
      'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test',
      'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-eureka-server'
  )


dependencyManagement {
    imports {
        mavenBom "org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-dependencies:Finchley.M5"
        mavenBom 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-gateway:2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT'
    }
}
```

Whwn I am trying to do refresh gradle project, getting below error

CONFIGURE SUCCESSFUL in 0s
Could not resolve: org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-eureka:
Could not resolve: org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-eureka-server:

Can you please confirm my spring boot and cloud version?

Answer (score 13):

They were renamed in Edgware. This one to spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client. The other to spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-server.

Comment: Hello Spencer,I have updated this, and my api service getting started, but when i check the health, it is not UP...and also i am getting the error "Spring MVC found on classpath, which is incompatible with Spring Cloud Gateway at this time. Please remove spring-boot-starter-web dependency."

Comment: Also , can you please confirm that the versions of spring boot, cloud are fine and I am not missing any dependency

Comment: Checkout the [release notes](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-cloud/wiki/Spring-Cloud-Edgware-Release-Notes) for a list of name changes