# pom.xml gives error every time on adding new dependency

Tags: maven, spring-boot, pom.xml, netflix-eureka

I have a pom.xml file error with dependencies/plugins. Every time i am adding new dependency, it gives error related to version. Currently it is giving error related to Eureka server.

Error message after adding dependency for Eureka naming server in pom.xml

Project build error: 'dependencies.dependency.version' for org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-eureka:jar is missing.

pom.xml file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.4.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.in28minutes.microservices</groupId>
    <artifactId>currency-conversion-service</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>currency-conversion-service</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>Greenwich.SR3</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-config</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
             <artifactId>spring-cloud-netflix-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-openfeign</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency> <--- ERROR HERE
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-eureka</artifactId>

        </dependency>
         <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-ribbon</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [spring-cloud-starter-eureka is not resolving when i use Finchley.M5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48766137/spring-cloud-starter-eureka-is-not-resolving-when-i-use-finchley-m5) and/or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51921033/project-build-error-dependencies-dependency-version-for-org-springframework-c

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That dependency is deprecated, so its not included in the imported dependency managment, see also the remark at https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.cloud/spring-cloud-starter-eureka:

> Spring Cloud Starter Eureka (deprecated, please use spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client

So just use:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client</artifactId>
</dependency>
```